# How to get the customers who has multiple product values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

I have a table with 2 columns
table(cust, prod)

Below is the table

```
cust                prod
1100000000104440000 PRODUCT_1
1100000000083280000 PRODUCT_1
1100000000104440000 PRODUCT_2
1000000000000950000 PRODUCT_2
```

I'm trying to get the customer who bought more than one product. The expected output must be

```
cust                prod
1100000000104440000 PRODUCT_1
1100000000104440000 PRODUCT_2
```

I wrote below SQL query, but it's not working

```
WHERE table.prod IN ('PRODUCT_1', 'PRODUCT_2')
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `QUALIFY` and windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT prod) OVER(PARTITION BY cust) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for mysql, you can modify and make it compatible with ansi-sql

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
JOIN
    (SELECT table1.cust, COUNT(table1.prod) FROM table1
    GROUP BY cust
    HAVING COUNT(table1.prod) > 1)
as a ON a.cust = table1.cust
```

Check out this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qFkNt3E6a8J6xAjLnXmwys/1)

Comment: Your query is ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an `uncorrelated subquery`

```
select *
from t
where cust in (select cust
                from t
                group by cust
                having count(distinct prod)>1)
```